# Running portion of script based on day of week

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've written this code which is executed using the Script trigger function in Google Sheets.

```
function addToList() 
{
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Accts and Targets'); //source sheet name
var t1 = ss.getSheetByName('Over Time'); //target sheet name
var source = s1.getRange("E21:G21");
var last_row = t1.getLastRow();
var target = t1.getRange("A"+(last_row+1));
t1.insertRowAfter(last_row);
source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});


var tt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var v1 = tt.getSheetByName('Accts and Targets'); //source sheet name
var w1 = tt.getSheetByName('Weekly State'); //target sheet name
var source = v1.getRange("b67:i67");
var last_row = w1.getLastRow();
var target = w1.getRange("A"+(last_row+1));
w1.insertRowAfter(last_row);
source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
}
```

To summarize, the script copies and pastes data from a common source sheet to two different destination sheets.

It is split into 2 portions with a blank line separating the first from the second portion.

Both portions execute daily (as I set it up to do - using the trigger function).

I tried to run the two portions as separate functions and use the trigger functionality, but the second portion didn't work; while the first worked correctly each day.

I'd like some help to insert code that would execute the second portion - BUT only on Mondays.

I see a function called "onWeekDay()", but I can't find the right code to use to have it work.

I suspect I need to add an if statement ahead of this line:

```
var tt = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
```

that only executes from this line to the end of the function on Monday's.

Comment: Welcome. What do you mean by that second portion didn't work? Did the trigger ran? Is there an error message on https://script.google.com? How do you set both portions as separate functions? How do you set the triggers for each separate function?

Comment: Initially I created Addtolist which only included the first 10 lines of code. I then used the trigger functionality and that worked for me as designed.

I then built a second function and tried to use the trigger functionality on that as well, but it didn't work. I can't remember the error message. This second function only need to run weekly. When I ran the trigger it of course executed both portions.

So now I needed to find a line or two of code (which you wrote - thank you), to not execute the second portion unless it was a Monday.

I'll test the code later today/tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function addToList() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var s1 = ss.getSheetByName('Accts and Targets'); 
  var t1 = ss.getSheetByName('Over Time');
  var source = s1.getRange(21,5,1,3);
  t1.insertRowAfter(t1.getLastRow());
  var target=t1.getRange(t1.getLastRow()+1,1);
  source.copyTo((target),{contentsOnly:true});
  if(new Date().getDay()==1) {
    var tt = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var v1 = tt.getSheetByName('Accts and Targets');
    var w1 = tt.getSheetByName('Weekly State');
    var source = v1.getRange(67,2,1,8);
    w1.insertRowAfter(w1.getLastRow());
    var target = w1.getRange(w1.getLastRow()+1,1);
    source.copyTo((target), {contentsOnly:true});
  }
}
```

Comment: the IF statement does not execute for the day = Monday (or as noted in the code = 1).

Comment: Did you view executions and see if there was an error?

Comment: I don't get an error message, it simply doesn't execute the lines of code following the if statement - despite that today is a Monday.

It does execute the expected result for the first 8 lines of code..

Comment: Sorry Cooper... After I looked back on the spreadsheet, it appears that it did execute the code correctly - Except it inserted the new line into row 10 of the destination sheet (which was hidden by a graph I had built).

It should have inserted the line after the last row (like it does for the first portion).

I'm looking at why it did that now.

Comment: Well, It's time to run it in the debugger and figure out what's wrong.

Comment: Cooper. When you edited the 4th last row you changed the designation from getLastRow to getLastColumn. This created the incorrect positioning of the destination copy row. Once I changed it back to getLastRow - the snippet worked as I wanted it to work.

Thanks again and sorry for the confusion on my side...

Comment: That's great.  You got it running. Thanks